# Анимированый счётчик при прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующую идею:
У меня есть блок, внутри которого есть `span` с числами, как сделать так, чтобы анимация чисел происходила только тогда, когда пользователь доскролит именно до этого блока.
Сейчас анимация происходит при загрузки страницы.
Не совсем понимаю где ошибся:

```
var flag     = true,
        win      = $(window).scrollTop(),
        blockTop = $(".support_month").offset().top;

    $(window).scrollTop(function () {
        if (  blockTop < win ) {
            while (flag) {
                $('.counter-number').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                        Counter: $(this).text()
                    }, {
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        step: function (now) {
                            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                        }
                    });
                });
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    })

;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let blockTop = $(".support_month").offset().top,   // Получаем отступ блока
    wh       = window.innerHeight,                 // Высота видимой части
    flag     = true,                               // Флаг активации
    counter  = _ => {
      if(counter._count > 10){                     // Если счёт дошёл до 10, то
        counter._count = 0;                        // Сбросим
        flag = !flag;                              // Всё
        return;                                    // И выходим
      }
      
      $('.counter-number').text(counter._count++); // Иначе делаем что нужно
      
      setTimeout(counter, 500);                    // И ставим таймер на следующую итерацию
    };

counter._count = 0;

$(window).scroll(_ => { // Слушаем скролл окна
  if(flag && blockTop < $(window).scrollTop() + wh){ // Если флаг позволяет запустить таймер и скролл дошёл
    flag = !flag; // Меняем доступность флага (чтобы каждый раз не запускался счётчик и не навешал сотню таймеров)
    counter();    // Запускаем что надо
  }
});
```

```css
#mock{
  height: 1000px;
}
.counter-number{
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px; top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mock'><div class='counter-number'></div></div>
<div class='support_month'>Yippee ki-yay, user!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да лехчайше, с помощью этого [плагина](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) это легко. Сам им пользуюсь, вот [пример](https://vostoksisters.github.io/gallery/).

Примерный код такой, чтобы включить плагин в дело (предворительно через скрипт подключаешь его в html, всё указано в [репозитории](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)):

```
AOS.init(
{
  duration: 300
});
```

В html пишешь к элементу `data-aos` и анимацию, типа такого:

```
<div data-aos="fade-up"></div>
```

Это важно, по  `data-aos` скрипт будет искать элемент.
Насчет кастомизации не переживай, можно настроить всякое: чтобы анимация была 1 раз, вращалась а не фейдилась вверх, как я в пример привел и всё в таком роде. Всё это на репозитории есть, вопрос не в этом тут стоит. 
Просто как решение вполне себе, тоже такое интересовало) 
Но сразу скажу, я потратил минут 30 на поиск, почему не работает скрипт: нужно ещё скачать стили для него (в нем прописаны сами анимации к `data-aos` атрибуту), их можно найти на сайте скрипта в самом-самом низу.
Но вынесенные стили - это скорее плюс чем лишняя заморока, ведь тогда можно переназначить транзишны через свой css, что весьма понятно и удобно.

Comment: мне никак не подходит ваш плагин так как я делаю плавное увеличение чисел от 0 до нужного значения, с тем же успехом я мог бы воспользоваться библиотекой animate.css

Comment: @ChromeChrome, в вопросе этого не указано (:
Код делает какой-то каунтер, я бегло это увидел, но если читать именно сам вопрос, то чтобы начать анимацию - это решение. Как я понял, тебе нужно плавно каунтить счетчик при скролле, а это уже совсем другой вопрос ведь. Редактируй тогда свой, а мой будет нести минусы. Вот и помогай теперь :D